# If $\| x \|$ is a norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$, when is $\| A x \|$ a norm?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces

I'm doing some homework where I'm asked to show whether given functions are norms in a finite vector space. One such function can be expressed as $\| Ax \|_\infty$ where $A$ has column vectors that form an orthogonal set (but not "orthonormal").

This got me thinking: if $\| x \|$ is a norm in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, under what conditions is $\| A x \|$ a norm if $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$?

Some cases I'm interested in:

- $A$ is orthogonal ($A^T = A^{-1}$)
- $A$ has orthogonal column vectors but not normalized
- $A$ is nonsingular

Edit: adding some analysis I've done to explore this...

Assume:

- $\| \cdot \|$ is a norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$
- $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is nonsingular

Norm conditions:

1. Because $\| \cdot \|$ is a norm, $\| Ax \| = 0$ implies $Ax = 0$. Since $A$ is nonsingular, $x = 0$.
2. Because $\| \cdot \|$ is a norm, $\| \lambda Ax \| = |\lambda| \| Ax \|$. This is pretty trivial.
3. $\|A(x + y)\| \le \| Ax \| + \| Ay \|$.

Is this proof correct?

Comment: Well, try to verify the properties of a norm :) what have you tried so far, respectively where are you stuck?

Comment: What is stopping you from calculating $||A\lambda  x||$, verifying the triangle inequality and checking whether $||Ax|| = 0$ may occur for nonzero $x$?

Comment: Sorry and thanks, I'll edit my question to add some work on this!

Comment: I added a tentative proof of if $A$ is nonsingular, then $\| Ax \|$ is a norm. I feel like I am missing something. Thank you for your constructive criticism.

Comment: No, that's fine. If you really have the feeling that you are missing something you should do this more formally, i.e. define $||x||_A := ||Ax||$ for some known norm $||.||$ and verify the relevant statements in such a way that you start with an expression for $||.||_A$, translate it into $||.||$ terms, use the pertaining property for $||.||$ and again transform back to an expression using $||.||_A$. This may be trivial in this case, but this kind of discipline can be useful for more complicated questions, and it's worth doing the exercise if you feel unsure.

Comment: Thank you so much, @Thomas. Noted (and that makes sense).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your proof is correct.

Actually, the fact that the matrix is invertible (what you call nonsingular) is both a sufficient and necessary condition. You proved that it is sufficient. Now it is necessary because if $A$ is not invertible, then there exists $x_0 \neq 0$ such that $Ax_0\neq 0$, and then
$$
\|Ax_0\| = 0
$$
but with $x_0 \neq 0$. So in this case $x\mapsto \|Ax\|$ is not a norm.

Comment: brilliant. thank you!!